# How do I bind multiple dropdowns in my ASP.NET MVC Edit Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, html-helper

I have a viewmodel that contains a number of properties, a SelectList, and an array of child objects.

```
public class RoundViewModel
{
    public int RoundId { get; set; }
    public string RoundName { get; set; }
    public SelectList Teams { get; private set; }
    public List<GameViewModel> Games { get; set; }
}

public class GameViewModel
{
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }
    public DateTime GameTimeGMT { get; set; }
}
```

There can be a variable number of games per round, and I'm trying to bind the same `Teams` SelectList to each dropdown I put on the page:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CodeId) %>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoundNumber) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RoundNumber) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoundNumber) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoundName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RoundName) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoundName) %>
        </div>

        <%     
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Games.Count; i++)
        {
        %>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Game:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.DropDownList("Games[" + i + "].HomeTeamId", Model.Teams, "--No Game--", new { value = Model.Games[i].HomeTeamId })%> VS 
        <%= Html.DropDownList("Games[" + i + "].AwayTeamId", Model.Teams, "--No Game--", new { value = Model.Games[i].AwayTeamId })%>

            <%= Html.TextBox("Games[" + i + "].GameTimeGMT", Model.Games[i].GameTimeGMT, new { Class = "calendar", value = Model.Games[i].GameTimeGMT })%>
        </div>
        <% } %>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

A similar view works fine for the Create operation, but I can't seem to set the existing selection in each of the dropdown lists.  You can see I'm explicitly setting the datetime for each game.

The `new { value = Model.Games[i].HomeTeamId }` line sets an attribute on the `<select>` html element, but obviously this isn't going to work.  I thought about setting another attribute and using jQuery to set the selected item, but it feels even more hacky than the existing code.

I'm fairly new to MVC, so I can definitely appreciate if I'm doing this all the wrong way.  Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the constructor of a SelectList object then you can see it takes an IEnumerable list of objects as its source and other parameters to set the data and text fields and also the selected item.

Is there any particular reason your View model stores a SelectList rather than say a List of Teams? Then you would be able to do

```
Html.DropDownList("Games[" + i + "].HomeTeamId", 
    new SelectList(Model.Teams, Model.Games[i].HomeTeamId));

public class RoundViewModel
{
    ....
    public IList<TeamObject> Teams { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Awesome, that suggestion did it.  Honestly, I was using a SelectList because that's what most of the simpler examples I came across were using.